# Format text field to 2 decimal places without entering a decimal (SwiftUI)

Tags: swiftui

In a text field, I'd like, when a user enters a number e.g. 12345, it gets formatted as 123.45. The user never needs to enter a decimal place, it just uses the 2 right most numbers as the decimal places. The field should only allow numbers too. This is for a SwiftUI project. Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Comment: Did you try anything to achieve that ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Because there of a two way binding between what you enter and what is being shown in the TextField view it seems not possible to interpolate the displayed number entered. I would suggest a small hack:

- create a ZStack with a TextField and a Text View superimposed.
- the foreground font of the entered text in the TextField is clear or white `.foregroundColor(.clear)`
- the keyboard is only number without decimal point: `.keyboardType(.numberPad)`
- use `.accentColor(.clear)` to hide the cursor
- the results are displayed in a Text View with formatting `specifier: "%.2f"`

It would look like

[image]

This is the code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var enteredNumber = ""
    var enteredNumberFormatted: Double {
        return (Double(enteredNumber) ?? 0) / 100
    }
    var body: some View {

        Form {
            Section {
                ZStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    TextField("", text: $enteredNumber)
                        .keyboardType(.numberPad).foregroundColor(.clear)
                        .textFieldStyle(PlainTextFieldStyle())
                        .disableAutocorrection(true)
                        .accentColor(.clear)
                    Text("\(enteredNumberFormatted, specifier: "%.2f")")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks very much! Don't know if I had to, but I switched the order of the Text and TextField so the Text didn't stop me clicking through to the TextField. Thanks again, really appreciate your help. :-)

Comment: Happy to hear that this helped!  yes, the order in this case do not matter, would work either way.

Answer (score 2):

With Swift UI the complete solution is

1. TextField allow numeric value only
2. Should accept only one comma (".")
3. Restrict decimal point upto x decimal place

File NumbersOnlyViewModifier

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI
import Combine
struct NumbersOnlyViewModifier: ViewModifier {
    
    @Binding var text: String
    var includeDecimal: Bool
    var digitAllowedAfterDecimal: Int = 1
    
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .keyboardType(includeDecimal ? .decimalPad : .numberPad)
            .onReceive(Just(text)) { newValue in
                var numbers = "0123456789"
                let decimalSeparator: String = Locale.current.decimalSeparator ?? "."
                if includeDecimal {
                    numbers += decimalSeparator
                }
                if newValue.components(separatedBy: decimalSeparator).count-1 > 1 {
                    let filtered = newValue
                    self.text = isValid(newValue: String(filtered.dropLast()), decimalSeparator: decimalSeparator)
                } else {
                    let filtered = newValue.filter { numbers.contains($0)}
                    if filtered != newValue {
                        self.text = isValid(newValue: filtered, decimalSeparator: decimalSeparator)
                    } else {
                        self.text = isValid(newValue: newValue, decimalSeparator: decimalSeparator)
                    }
                }
            }
    }
    
    private func isValid(newValue: String, decimalSeparator: String) -> String {
        guard includeDecimal, !text.isEmpty else { return newValue }
        let component = newValue.components(separatedBy: decimalSeparator)
        if component.count > 1 {
            guard let last = component.last else { return newValue }
            if last.count > digitAllowedAfterDecimal {
                let filtered = newValue
               return String(filtered.dropLast())
            }
        }
        return newValue
    }
}
```

File View+Extenstion

```
extension View {
    func numbersOnly(_ text: Binding<String>, includeDecimal: Bool = false) -> some View {
        self.modifier(NumbersOnlyViewModifier(text: text, includeDecimal: includeDecimal))
    }
}
```

File ViewFile

```
 TextField("", text: $value,  onEditingChanged: { isEditing in
      self.isEditing = isEditing
   }) 
  .foregroundColor(Color.neutralGray900)
  .numbersOnly($value, includeDecimal: true)
  .font(.system(size: Constants.FontSizes.fontSize22))
  .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
```